# RadixUI/Shadcn unexpected Portal behaviour (does not reset state)

Tags: reactjs, radix, shadcnui

I'm using RadixUI `Dialog` (https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/dialog) and I want to completely reset its state on closing. Here is a working example where I moved the its content to separate component which define `input` state: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/pedantic-hellman-4k565n?file=%2FApp.jsx%3A17%2C27

Try to open modal, set some content to input and close it. Then try to open it again and input is correctly empty so it reset entirely. HOWEVER, when I move `Dialog.DialogPortal` to `ButtonDialogContent` component, the state does not reset at all and when reopening, the old vallue is shown. Why does it happen?